# how to list all checkout items in vs.net 2010 tfs?

Tags: visual-studio

how can I list all checked out items in vs.net 2010 tfs? where in 
vs.net 2010 can I find this /do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Pending Changes" toolwindow. Select the View > Other Windows > Pending Changes menu items.

You can also use `tf status` command, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s5ae285.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Attrice has a nice UI in which you can see these kind of things. You can see the list of all checked out files by anybody and even act commands on these files. See [Attrice TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to list all user checkouts grouped by users. I used the following command to list checkouts into separate text files per user, so I can ask individual users to clear their checkouts. Hope this will be useful for anyone planning to housekeep or migrate TFS.

"FOR" is an inbuilt dos command. You should run this on "Visual Studio Command Prompt". "MyUserList.txt" is a text file that lists all TFS accounts. One account per line in the file.

```
FOR /F  "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %i in (MyUserList.txt) do tf status /collection:http://<your TFS Server>:<Your TFS Port>/tfs/tfscollection /user:%i\%j >>  %j.txt
```